# BSCMAKE Warning BK4503

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Вроде бы не мешает, вроде - мозолит глаза. Может, это действительно влияет на что-либо, не зря же это варнинг:

`BSCMAKE : warning BK4503: minor error in .SBR file '%filepath%' ignored`

Искал ответы на разных ресурсах, но увы. Например, [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27862346/visual-studio-2013-suddenly-compiling-really-slow-after-bk4503-minor-error-appea). На MSDN вообще из указаний только "перекомпилируйте", и это не помогает. У меня Visual Studio 2015. Пока что в режиме Debug.

Как избавиться?

---

Командная строка С/С++:

```
/Yu"stdafx.h" 
/FR"x64\Debug\" 
/GS 
/W3 
/Zc:wchar_t 
/ZI 
/Gm 
/Od 
/sdl 
/Fd"x64\Debug\vc140.pdb" 
/Zc:inline 
/fp:precise 
/D "WIN32" 
/D "_DEBUG" 
/D "_CONSOLE" 
/D "_LIB" 
/D "_UNICODE" 
/D "UNICODE" 
/errorReport:prompt 
/WX- 
/Zc:forScope 
/RTC1 
/Gd 
/MDd 
/Fa"x64\Debug\" 
/EHsc 
/nologo 
/Fo"x64\Debug\" 
/Fp"x64\Debug\Yarnet.pch"
```

Командная строка компоновщика:

```
/OUT:"C:\Users\804097\Desktop\VS\Yarnet\x64\Debug\Yarnet.exe" 
/MANIFEST 
/NXCOMPAT 
/PDB:"C:\Users\804097\Desktop\VS\Yarnet\x64\Debug\Yarnet.pdb" 
/DYNAMICBASE "opencv_world310d.lib" "kernel32.lib" "user32.lib"
"gdi32.lib" "winspool.lib" "comdlg32.lib" "advapi32.lib" "shell32.lib" 
"ole32.lib" "oleaut32.lib" "uuid.lib" "odbc32.lib" "odbccp32.lib" 
/MACHINE:X64 
/INCREMENTAL 
/PGD:"C:\Users\804097\Desktop\VS\Yarnet\x64\Debug\Yarnet.pgd" 
/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE 
/MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" 
/ManifestFile:"x64\Debug\Yarnet.exe.intermediate.manifest" 
/ERRORREPORT:PROMPT 
/NOLOGO 
/LIBPATH:"D:\opencv\build\x64\vc14\lib" 
/TLBID:1
```

Comment: Предупреждение возникает несмотря на установку `Preserve SBR Files` в `No` (из ответа по упомянутой ссылке)?

Comment: @alexolut, да, если бы это решилось подобным образом, я бы и не стал задавать такой вопрос.

Comment: Удалять файлы вручную пробовали? Проект вообще большой? Можно это как-то повторить с чистого листа?

Comment: @alexolut, насколько я знаю, "очистить решение" очищает всё, кроме `log`-файлов. То есть, и `.sbr` тоже. Эти `.sbr`-файлы каждый раз генерируются компилятором, так что очистка не значит что-либо особенного в данном случае. Проект достаточно большой лично для меня, и переносить его в новый будет затруднительно.

Comment: @brenoritvrezorkre скажите, с какими флагами идет сборка проекта?

Comment: @goldstar_labs, так, на всякий случай скину полные для компоновщика и компилятора в описании.

Comment: @brenoritvrezorkre, За генерацию .sbr файлов отвечает флаг /FR, в студии это Properties - C/C++ - Browse Information, данная опция генерирует .sbr файлы на основе каждого .obj файла, по которым потом можно удобно сопоставлять символы с исходным кодом. МСДН говорит, что чаще всего это проявляется при использовании stdafx.h в паре с rtti (/GR). Теоретически от этого должен спасать полный ребилд проекта, до внесения следующих правок в код). Если мозолит глаза, то можете отключить, особого вреда проекту не будет.

Comment: @goldstar_labs, а никаких ошибок в настройках не заметно? Та проблема с opencv может быть в них, возможно.